# Angularjs how to search through multiple json files/url

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Does any one have any clue on how to create a search function that is able to search through multiple json files or from multiple json url? Can't seem to find any related question. 
PS: Something similar to the ng-model method, where u search through the json file.
Just that in my case i have multiple json files 
( Still new to angularjs, sorry if the question is dumb or unclear )

Comment: please provide more context. any example what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Something similar to the ng-model i guess? Just that from my knowledge, ng-model is used to search through only one json file. ( I am still new to angularjs ) And i am trying to search through multiple files now

Comment: what does "similar to the ng-model" mean?  `ng-model` is a binding attribute; it is used to connect an HTML element with a JavaScript object property. What does that have to do with searching a json file?

Comment: Uhh, dont people usually use ng-model to bind with a ng-repeat and filter out the search

Comment: well you certainly *could* use an `ng-repeat` filter to perform a search, but that isn't a search of a json file, that is a search of a JavaScript object.  That object definitely could be populated by a call to a json file... maybe you want to ask about how to consolidate multiple json calls into a single object?  or are you asking how to have `ng-repeat` filter multiple objects?  either way, your question is too broad, and really needs a [mcve] to show what you are trying to accomplish.